# Incorrect free and total space figures given for mapped network drive

Tags: windows-7, dropbox, onedrive, google-drive, network-drive

In Windows 7, to map my Dropbox folder as a network drive under My Computer I use `net use X: "\\localhost\Users\<username>\Dropbox"`. This works fine and I do the same for Google Drive and OneDrive.

The problem is the free and total space figures given for these drives is wrong; instead Windows is using those from my own hard drive rather than what is free for the relevant account.

[image: demo]

Is they anyway of correcting this?

Comment: Of course it is.  Windows does not have the capability to query your account, determine who much space you have, and display that.

Comment: Okay that is why I have asked this question to determine if there is anyway of correcting this or finding a way around it. Your tone suggests my question is unwarranted?

Comment: What you want is not possible if you want to map these folders in the way you describe.  Most people overestimate their ability to understand the tone of the written word by other people.  If I thought this question was not unwarranted I would flat out tell you exactly that.  The question is fine.  There might be third-party tools that can setup a network drive with more specific conditions, but I honestly doubt it, even the Google Drive explorer intergration doesn't know how much space you have.

Comment: I don't upvote bad questions.  **I upvoted this question.**

Comment: Appreciate your feedback and upvote - I shall do some more research on other possible tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[NetDrive](http://www.netdrive.net/) will integrate with Windows and allow you to connect Dropbox, Google Drive and OneDrive accounts (as well as others) and map them as network drives (or local drives) and as I requested NetDrive also gives the correct free/total space.

30 days free trial thereafter a one off $45 fee for a single license

[image: netdrive]

Answer (score 0):

It's displaying the correct numbers for the drive the folder is located on. Windows does not know how to get this data for your account.  One possible way round it would be to write a driver/app that installs as a drive and has the ability to query for your account. I don't know if such a driver/app already exists

Answer (score 0):

It might not be a solution to your problem but since i am not allowed to write a comment i have to write it this way.

In general SMB shares only show the free/total space of their host drive as you already noticed.

What do you exactly try to achieve?

Is your primary goal managing your shared folders (dropbox, google, ...) in different drives showing the free/total space for every drive as you configured it?

Then you could think about using VHDs. Win7 can mount it without using additional drivers.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VHD_%28file_format%29

I'm not sure how Windows handles the space the vhd file itself reserves on your hdd. If it really reserves all the space on creation or if it expands whenever more space is needed but doesn't shrink when you free memory, you might run into trouble with your huge onedrive file.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I have my 3 cloud accounts mapped as network drives simply for the convenience of having them tidily under My Computer and accessible in one place rather than scattered about. Do you know of a command similar to `net use ...` for mapping in the same way using VHD?

Comment: you'll have to create it first. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd744338%28v=ws.10%29.aspx
I'm sorry for the missing part of my comment. just hit return and posted it by accident

this explains the mounting part https://angler.wordpress.com/2010/03/11/windows-7-auto-mount-vhds-at-startup/

Comment: And this will work for a networked cloud account such as Dropbox? Have you done this successfully yourself before?

Comment: I've done it once. This acts as a virtual disk which is stored inside a single file. That's why you might get problems like i said in the last paragraph of my answer